# Multiple verify_password callbacks on flask-httpauth

Tags: python, flask, flask-httpauth

Working on a Flask application which will have separate classes of routes to be authenticated against: user routes and host routes(think Airbnb'esque where users and hosts differ substantially).

Creating a single verify_password callback and login_required combo is extremely straightforward, however that isn't sufficient, since some routes will need host authentication and others routes will necessitate user authentication. Essentially I will need to have one verify_password/login_required for user and one for host, but I can't seem to figure out how that would be done since it appears that the callback is global in respect to auth's scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I intended that to be handled is by creating two HTTPAuth objects. Each gets its own `verify_password` callback, and then you can decorate each route with the decorator that is appropriate.

Comment: Oh, wow, yes after you say that, it is immediately obvious... for some reason I thought the auth object was a Singleton.